# How to get success message in popup using custom form?

Tags: 7

**How to get success message in popup form  here is my code :**

```
   <?php
 /**
 * Implements security_settings_form().
*/
function security_settings_block_info() {
$blocks['testing'] = array(
'info' => t('testing1'), 
'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, //there are a number of caching options for this
 );

 return $blocks;
 }

function security_settings_block_view($delta = ''){
  switch($delta){
    case 'testing':
  if(user_access('access content')){ //good idea to check user perms here
     $block['subject'] = t('testing');
     $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('security_settings_form');
     //$block['content'] = security_settings_form();
     return $block;
  }
  break;
  }
  }
function security_settings_form($form, &$form_state) {  
$form["wrapper"] = array("#markup" => "<div id='test-ajax'></div>");

   $result = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd');
  $result->fields('ttd');
  $result->condition('ttd.vid', 2, '=');
  $results = $result->execute()->fetchAll();
   $termName = '';
   foreach($results as $record){    

   $v[]=$record->name;


}
$form['cities'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Click on your city'),
//'#multiple' => true,
'#options' => $v,

 '#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-class-1')),
  );
   $form['email'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Enter email'),

   '#validate' => array('security_settings_form_validate'),
 );  
    $form['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',

    '#value' =>  'Save',

     "#ajax" => array(
  "callback" => "dr_search_test_form_callback", 

  "wrapper" => "test-ajax",
  "effect" => "fade")

    );

return $form;
 }

function security_settings_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
$email = $form_state['values']['email'];

 // Verify that the email address is valid.
   if (!valid_email_address($email)) {
  form_set_error('email',('You must provide a valid email address.'));
  }

}

  function dr_search_test_form_callback($form, $form_state) {


   global $user; 
   $v=db_insert('security_settings')
   ->fields(array(
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],   
  'cities' => $form_state['values']['cities'],
    ))->execute();


   $email = $form_state['values']['email'];
   if (valid_email_address($email)) {
   $message = array('A new entry has been submitted');
   $to = 'abc@gmail.com';
   $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'Website Information Request',
     );
       if (drupal_mail('security_settings', 'some_mail_key',   $to,          language_default(), $params)) {
    drupal_set_message('Thanks, email sent.');  //success message  
   } else {
    drupal_set_message('Email not sent.');
  }
  }

return "<div id='test-ajax'>".$v."</div>";
  }
 function security_settings_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
   $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
   $message['body'] = $params['body'];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the messages to the ajax form by adding the following to your ajax callback function (you'll need to remove your current return value)

```
$messages = array('#theme' => 'status_messages');
$commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('#form_id', render($messages));

return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

Make sure to change #form_id to the actual ID of your form, or use whatever jQuery selector you want to prepend the messages to.

Comment: One more thing if i render the same form twice in page--front.tpl.php in header and footer region why its showing error message only once in header message not in footer region

Comment: If you are using a jquery selector that is an ID (not a class), it will only work with the first ID it finds on the page, as IDs are supposed to be unique. You'll need to find a different jquery selector to work with if you want to send it to both forms. But it's a different question than this one, so if you want to know more you should start a new question.